# Application of XGBoost in R to data with incomplete values of a categorical variable

Tags: r, machine-learning, xgboost

How do you cope with application of XGBoost in R? I have a problem with that, since when a categorical type column of data does not contain all its possible values (which the model accounts for), I get an error: "Featured names stored in `object` and `newdata` are different".

I know how to get around that problem by preparing input data in a different way, i.e. by adding sufficient amount of dummy variables to cover all possible values of categorical variables I intend to account for. E.g. if a feature F I want to use takes on values 'a', 'b' or 'c', I create an XGBoost model using features is_a, is_b and is_c. Then if in my input data, to which I want to apply the model, feature F comes only with 'b' or 'c' values, I am still using those 3 features, having is_c equal to 0 at each observation.

But that’s not how I want to do it, since it seems to be quite tedious in general and besides I don’t come across similar problems when using different models, e.g. logistic regression by glm() function.

So my question is: is it possible to apply XGBoost model to observations containing categorical (factor) variables with incomplete values? `Incomplete` meaning here: not all values the model accounts for.

I have prepared an example to show that case, based on mtcars data. Let's say we want to have a classification model predicting gear-box type (automatic or manual, column 'am'). One of possible features is weight (column 'wt') and we want to use weight data as a factor type feature rather than as a feature of continuous type.

```
library(xgboost)
library(dplyr)
library(dummies)

##### Example 0: wt as a continuous variable (no errors on data with incomplete values) #####
# Train:
data_train <- mtcars
model_matrix_train <- model.matrix(am ~ ., data = data_train)
xgb_data_train <- xgb.DMatrix(model_matrix_train, label = data_train$am)
param <- list(max_depth = 2, eta = 1, objective = "binary:logistic")
model_xgb <- xgb.train(param, xgb_data_train, nrounds = 100)

# Test on data with incomplete wt values:
data_test <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(wt < 4)
model_matrix_test <- model.matrix(am ~ ., data = data_test)
xgb_data_test <- xgb.DMatrix(model_matrix_test, label = data_test$am)
predict(model_xgb, newdata = xgb_data_test, type="prob")


##### Example 1: wt as a factor (error on data with incomplete values) #####
# Train:
data_train <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(wt = factor(
    case_when(
      wt < 2 ~ "1_2",
      wt < 3 ~ "2_3",
      wt < 4 ~ "3_4",
      wt < 5 ~ "4_5",
      TRUE ~ "5_6"
    ))
  )
model_matrix_train <- model.matrix(am ~ ., data = data_train)
xgb_data_train <- xgb.DMatrix(model_matrix_train, label = data_train$am)
param <- list(max_depth = 2, eta = 1, objective = "binary:logistic")
model_xgb <- xgb.train(param, xgb_data_train, nrounds = 100)

# Test on data with incomplete wt values:
data_test <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(wt < 4) %>% 
  mutate(wt = factor(
    case_when(
      wt < 2 ~ "1_2",
      wt < 3 ~ "2_3",
      wt < 4 ~ "3_4",
      wt < 5 ~ "4_5",
      TRUE ~ "5_6"
    ))
  )
model_matrix_test <- model.matrix(am ~ ., data = data_test)
xgb_data_test <- xgb.DMatrix(model_matrix_test, label = data_test$am)
predict(model_xgb, newdata = xgb_data_test, type="prob") # ERROR
```

I also tried using dummy variables for all relevant cases of wt (instead of transforming wt into a factor variable). The result was similar to the above example 1:

```
##### Example 2: wt as a dummy variable (error on data with incomplete values) #####
# Train:
data_train <- mtcars %>% 
  mutate(wt = factor(
    case_when(
      wt < 2 ~ "1_2",
      wt < 3 ~ "2_3",
      wt < 4 ~ "3_4",
      wt < 5 ~ "4_5",
      TRUE ~ "5_6"
    ))
  )
data_train <- dummy.data.frame(data_train, "wt", sep = "_")
model_matrix_train <- model.matrix(am ~ ., data = data_train)
xgb_data_train <- xgb.DMatrix(model_matrix_train, label = data_train$am)
param <- list(max_depth = 2, eta = 1, objective = "binary:logistic")
model_xgb <- xgb.train(param, xgb_data_train, nrounds = 100)

# Test on data with incomplete wt values:
data_test <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(wt < 4) %>% 
  mutate(wt = factor(
    case_when(
      wt < 2 ~ "1_2",
      wt < 3 ~ "2_3",
      wt < 4 ~ "3_4",
      wt < 5 ~ "4_5",
      TRUE ~ "5_6"
    ))
  )
data_test <- dummy.data.frame(data_test, "wt", sep = "_")
model_matrix_test <- model.matrix(am ~ ., data = data_test)
xgb_data_test <- xgb.DMatrix(model_matrix_test, label = data_test$am)
predict(model_xgb, newdata = xgb_data_test, type="prob") # ERROR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the reason for the missing feature in the input data is reasonable (not available categorical data) to the algorithm it makes no difference whether the feature is missing because the data does not contain a factor level or because the data is truly incomplete (missing a feature).

So I can only offer you a quicker way to encode new input data to always have the right feature levels:

```r
data_test <- mtcars %>% 
  filter(wt < 4) %>% 
  mutate(wt = factor(
    case_when(
      wt < 2 ~ "1_2",
      wt < 3 ~ "2_3",
      wt < 4 ~ "3_4",
      wt < 5 ~ "4_5",
      TRUE ~ "5_6"
    ), levels = c("1_2","2_3","3_4","4_5","5_6")) #instead of c(...) this could be variable with the stored factor levels from model creation
  )

data_test <- (data_test %>% cbind(model.matrix(~ wt-1, data = .) %>% data.frame())
```

This does two important things:

1. Encode factor levels

By providing the levels argument in your factor-conversion you will have all relevant levels. Besides supplying a manual list you always save the appropriate factor levels as a variable when you create the original model.

2. Use cbind and model.matrix() for dummies

Instead of using the dummy.data.frame function, use model.matrix() because it will encode automatic 0 for missing factor levels.

Comment: It seems to work well, thanks! Need to check it on real data.

Comment: It works fine. The reason it didn't was that I had omitted the `level` parameter, when redefining variable `wt`. Thanks again, @Fnguyen.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!